# Is it possible to make the result of secure multi-party computation only available to one party?

Tags: cryptography

According the ordinary definition of secure multi-party computation, all the parties will learn the final result but cannot learn others' input values.
My question is: is it possible to design a "secure multi-part computation" protocol such that only one party can learn the final result and no party can learn the input of others?

Thank you:)

Comment: Sure, Yao works like this and SMC (arithmetic secret sharing) is entirely flexible in this regard.

Comment: Are you looking for distributed randomization?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. In MPC the "functionality", f, defines the desired behaviour.

`f(x,y) = (out_1, out_2)`

Here, in the two party setting, x is the input of the first party, and y the input of the second, out_1 is the output of the first and out_2 the output of the second. The two outputs can be different.

A simple, very widely used example is Oblivious Transfer which is defined as:

`f((b_0, b_1), c) = (_, b_c)`

Here the first party inputs two values, (b_0, b_1) and the second party inputs a bit, c. The first party receives nothing, and the second party receives the b corresponding to it's choice, c.

For a concrete and through treatment of the matter I would refer you to [Lindell's seminal tutorial](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf) (section 4.2 is likely the part that will help the most).